# How to have 'this' available when returning a function from a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function (method) that returns a function, and it's being used in a class:

```
  public myMethod(): (row: number) => number {
    return (row) => {
      const newData = this.form[row]; // this.form is not defined
```

When returning the function (with `row` argument), I don't have access to `this` anymore. How should I refactor the function so that it has access to `this` of the class?

Comment: You're probably using something like `takeCallback(obj.myMethod)` change it to `takeCallback(() => obj.myMethod())` or change the definition to `public myMethod = (): ((row: number) => number) => {`

Comment: Oh right, so by changing the definition to the syntax you wrote I changed it into an arrow function? Thank you so much